# A problem involving Schwarz lemma (from Gamelin)

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I have a problem that I cannot solve; it was homework this past semester, I didn't get it then, and now I'm going over past problems and am stuck on it again.

It reads-- suppose $f(z)$ is analytic and satisfies $\mid{f(z)}\mid \leq 1$ for $|z|<1$. If $|f(0)|\geq r$, then 
$$|f(z)|\geq \frac{r-|z|}{1-r|z|} \qquad \forall |z|<r.$$

I am not sure how to apply Schwarz lemma to solve this.  This problem came in IX.1.5.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are you sure it is not $|f(z)|<1$ for $|z|<1$?

Comment: Well, that was a stupid question because we can assume that without loss of generality.

Answer (score 1):

Compose with a Möbius transformation of the disk carrying $f(0)$ to $0$ and then apply the Schwarz lemmma.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how that helps; we would end up with something like $|(f(z)-f(0))/(1-\bar{f(0)}f(z))|\leq |z|$. Is that somehow convertible into the above statement?